# swift GMSPlacePicker not showing the map

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to use placepicker in Google Places and it almost work. but it doesn't show map.
I already check my bundle id and API key but it fire error like this.How can i solve it?

> 2017-10-03 02:07:07.567436+0900 TimeLink[12798:6307433] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
>   2017-10-03 02:07:14.625956+0900 TimeLink[12798:6307322] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
>   2017-10-03 02:07:14.626209+0900 TimeLink[12798:6307322] Metal API Validation Enabled
>   2017-10-03 02:07:14.655942+0900 TimeLink[12798:6307322] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 12798 (TimeLink) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
>   2017-10-03 02:07:14.655985+0900 TimeLink[12798:6307322] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see )
>   2017-10-03 02:07:15.244151+0900 TimeLink[12798:6307322] ClientParametersRequest failed, 7 attempts remaining (0 vs 10). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to enable Google Map for ios.
really simple solution....

Comment: Thanks, You must enable google maps beside google places api.

Comment: I had the same problem, referring to API Key solve it, thank you